# What's the best practice for using .net core TimeZoneInfo with momentjs?

Tags: .net-core, timezone, momentjs

We store the user's timezone based on a list generated by the .netcore TimeZoneInfo.  From there, we allow the end user to specify dates and times using pickers, which are stored to the database.  All of this is working fine.  User picks a date and time, knowing that the timezone specifies "where".

On the frontend however, we use momentJS for formatting.  Since I know what the timezoneinfo Id is on the frontend as well, I was wondering if I can plug the date and timezoneid into momentjs to use the .format() command to manipulate dates.

I'm considering ditching momentjs, and formatting the dates on the backend, but momentjs affords our UI designers flexibility without having to redeploy.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- You really should consider replacing Moment with a more modern library.  Please read the [Moment Project Status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) (that I wrote) for further details.

  - If you *were* going to continue using Moment, you would also need the [Moment-Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on library to work with time zones.  If you choose a library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) as a replacement, time zone support is built-in.
  - Alternatively, You might just consider using [`Date.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) with the `timeZone` option.  If that meets your needs, then you won't need a library at all.
- `TimeZoneInfo` objects in .NET align their `Id` property with the platform they are running on.  That is, you get Windows IDs on Windows, and IANA IDs on Linux and macOS.  If you're unfamiliar with the difference, you should read [the `timezone` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- Windows time zone IDs are not useful with JavaScript libraries.  You will always need to use IANA IDs.

  - If you are running your server on Linux, you already have IANA values in your `TimeZoneInfo.Id` property, and are all set.  You can just use them directly in JavaScript.
  - If you are running your server on Windows, and are using .NET 6 or newer and are on a system with [ICU installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu), you can use [`TimeZoneInfo.TryConvertWindowsIdToIanaId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.tryconvertwindowsidtoianaid) to get the required IANA ID from a Windows ID.  You can read more about this in [the blog post I wrote for Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/#time-zone-conversion-apis).
  - If you are running on Windows and are on .NET 5 or lower, or are on older Windows without ICU installed, you can use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneConverter) library to convert between Windows and IANA IDs.